# How to stop dhclient writing syslog messages on Lubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

I'm running Lubuntu 11.10 and the package installs `dhclient`. Everything seems to work fine except that it keeps logging huge amounts of unnecessary `dhclient` status messages (several per second, every second) into the `syslog` file. This must be using up a large part on my CPU and disk resources.

How do I stop it from logging these messages?

I've looked at the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` configuration file but can't see how I could turn off the syslog messages.

Also, where is the startup file that actually runs the `dhclient` daemon? I've read that one can use the `-g` option to reduce message logging but this needs to be done in the commandline — I can't see where Lubuntu actually starts this daemon at boot-up (can't find it in the `/etc/init.d/` directory).

Answer (score 1):

From [Stop dhclient manually – Ubuntu Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+question/156183)

> Stopping a process is easy:
>
> 1. Identity the process id (pid) with the `ps ax` command (number in first column)
>
>    ```
>    ps ax | grep [d]hcli
>    ```
> 2. Send it a polite request to clean up and terminate:
>
>    ```
>    sudo kill pid f
>    ```
> 3. Do step 1 again, and if it still exists, blast it off the system:
>
>    ```
>    sudo kill -9 pid
>    ```